# plot pie chart in python for all unique values in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a situation where a list of 100s values but there are only 3 or 4 unique values. For example:
test=['abc','abc','bcd','bcd','bcd']
I would like to plot the pie chart in python which will automatically count the occurrences of each unique value and plot a pie chart or any graph.
in this example the pie chart should show that abc has 40% and bcd has 60%.

Comment: Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?#collections.Counter) from the `collections` library, to get a count and labels of the data you need to plot. And then use the `values` as sizes and `keys` as labels for the [pie](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-features-py) plot.

Comment: perfect and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the suggestions and codes from the  links from @thymen and came up with following code to make it work. Thank you

```
status_d=Counter(test)
print(status_d)

key_list = list(status_d.keys())
val_list = list(status_d.values())

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(val_list, labels=key_list, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

plt.show()
```